# C#: how assign a value to a string var without using switch

Tags: c#, switch-statement

First of all I must say that I am pretty new using C#. I have written this code block to assign a value to a string var depending on the value of another var. I have used the Switch statement:

```
    switch (_reader.GetString(0))
    {
       case "G":
            permiso.Area = "General";
            break;
       case "SIS":
            permiso.Area = "Sistems";
            break;
       case "SOP":
            permiso.Area = "Development";
            break;
       case "HLP":
            permiso.Area = "Support";
            break;
       }
```

Can I make this in an easier way in C#?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you define "easier" ? I  mean.. that's already done, so it's pretty hard to do something easier than "already done"..

Comment: I mean if exists in C# somo sentence that makes something like that:  my_string=my_string.decode(old_value0,new_value0, old_value1,new_value1, ...)

Comment: Is `var d = "G SIS SOP HLP".Split().Zip("General Sistems Development Support".Split()).ToDictionary(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);` or `var d = new Dictionary<string, string>(){ ["G"] = "General", ["SIS"] = "Sistems", ["SOP"] = "Development", ["HLP"] = "Support" }` followed by `permiso.Area = d[_reader.GetString(0)]` "easier"?

Comment: Readable Code Matters...support RCM to stop the madness

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp soo... no code in comments? :D

Comment: @CaiusJard I think (hope) what Ñyssa meant is that the OP's original code was very readable. Attempting to reduce code length in the vain hope that that makes it "easier" is something to be discouraged. I always tell my team members, when writing code, to think of the unfortunate programmer, who in three years' time needs to amend your code. If it takes them twice as long to understand it, you have written it badly in the first place.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out, that not only is the switch statement highly readable, it is also very fast at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Dictionary<string, string>(), which can store your "switch case" string as key and "switch case value" in value.

Example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
  {"G", "General"},
  {"SIS", "Sistems"},
  ...
}
So your code in order to access will be: 
var key = _reader.GetString(0);
if(dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value)
{
   permiso.Area = value;
}
else
{
  // handle not exists key situation
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Modern C# has a pattern matching switch

```
permiso.Area = _reader.GetString(0) switch {
  "G" => "General",
  "SIS" => "Sistems",
  "SOP" => "Development",
  "HLP" => "Support",
  _ => throw new InvalidOperationException($"The value {_reader.GetString(0)} is not handled")
};
```

C# will complain at you if you don't include the "else" at the end `_ =>`

Answer (score 0):

> I mean if exists in C# somo sentence that makes something like that: my_string=my_string.decode(old_value0,new_value0, old_value1,new_value1, ...)

If you're after something like Oracle's DECODE, you can write it:

```
string Decode(string expr, params string[] arr){

  for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i+=2)
    if(arr[i] == expr)
      return arr[i+1];
  return arr.Length % 2 == 0 ? null : arr[arr.Length-1];
}
```

You'd use it like:

```
permiso.Area = Decode(reader.GetString(0), "G", "General", "SIS", "Sistems", "SOP", "Development", "HLP", "Support");
```

If you want an ELSE, pass an odd length array (something after the "Support")

If you  want to be able to call it on a string, such as `reader.GetString(0).Decode("G" ...)` you can declare it in a static class and precede the first argument with `this` :

```
static string Decode(this string expr, ....)
```

That will make it an extension method, so it can be called "on a string"

Answer (score 0):

If you either have same mappings occur on multiple locations or generally use the same strings repeatingly (in conditions, e.g.), a more sophisticated and cleaner approach would be to use enums and their descriptions in the first place. This makes the code more readable as you can (and should) use the unique enum in the code and catch its description when needed.

You need this enum extension method to read enum descriptions:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

public static string Description(this Enum source) {
  DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])source
    .GetType()
    .GetField(source.ToString())
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
  return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : string.Empty;
}
```

Prepare the enum and its corresponding dictionary mappers. If possible, those enums should only have **one** unique description but you can define additional mapper dictionaries to your likings, e.g. when you need a simple short to long text mapper as in your example.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

// enum and its description
public enum PermissionArea {
  [Description("Development")]
  Development = 1,
  [Description("General")]
  General,
  [Description("Sistems")]
  Sistems,
  [Description("Support")]
  Support
}

public static class MyEnumDicts {
  // default mapping of enum to its description
  public static readonly Dictionary<PermissionArea, string> PermissionAreaToText = new Dictionary<PermissionArea, string>() {
    { PermissionArea.Development, PermissionArea.Development.Description() },
    { PermissionArea.General,     PermissionArea.General.Description() },
    { PermissionArea.Sistems,     PermissionArea.Sistems.Description() },
    { PermissionArea.Support,     PermissionArea.Support.Description() }
  };

  // mapping of enum to short text
  // (only if needed as it is better to only use one unique
  // value which is already set as description in the enum itself
  public static readonly Dictionary<PermissionArea, string> PermissionAreaToShortText = new Dictionary<PermissionArea, string>() {
    { PermissionArea.Development, "SOP" },
    { PermissionArea.General,     "G" },
    { PermissionArea.Sistems,     "SIS" },
    { PermissionArea.Support,     "Support" }
  };

  // add reverse mappers via linq
  public static readonly Dictionary<string, PermissionArea> TextToPermissionArea      = PermissionAreaToText.ToDictionary(m => m.Value, m => m.Key);
  public static readonly Dictionary<string, PermissionArea> ShortTextToPermissionArea = PermissionAreaToShortText.ToDictionary(m => m.Value, m => m.Key);
}
```

The usage could be as follows:

```
public void MyMethod(string permissionAreaShortText) {
  try {
    // map to enum (no switch or ifs etc. needed here)
    PermissionArea permissionArea = MyEnumDicts.ShortTextToPermissionArea[permissionAreaShortText];

    // now you can work via enums and do not
    // have to hassle with any strings anymore:
    switch (permissionArea) {
      case PermissionArea.Development: ...; break;
      case PermissionArea.General:     ...; break;
      case PermissionArea.Sistems:     ...; break;
      case PermissionArea.Support:     ...; break;
    }

    // output/use its description when needed:
    string permissionAreaText = permissionArea.Description();
    // ...

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    // error handling: short text is no permission area
    // ...
  }
}
```